# CUDA - nvcc -G - if not working properly

Tags: c, gcc, cuda, compiler-optimization, nvcc

I'm currently working on porting a lava flow model in CUDA (full code on github here: [Full source of the CUDA-SCIARA Fv2 lava flow model](https://github.com/knotman90/SCIARA_FV2_CUDA.git) .

**EDIT**

In order to reproduce the issue, use the instruction on github README in order to get a dev copy of the project SCIARA_FV2_CUDA_MULTICELLS. Then compile withouth -G option and passing as command line argument -c ../data/2006/PARAMETERS.cfg . (quoted code is at line 260 in this [file](https://github.com/knotman90/SCIARA_FV2_CUDA/blob/master/SCIARA_FV2_CUDA_MULTICELLS/src/CA_GPU.cuh#L260) )

I'm facing a problem with an if construct inside a **`__device__`** function.

Based on the current lava quantity and temperature it computes the new temperature and if it is lower than a constant parameter (the variable `d_PTsol=1143.0`) the lava is solified.

The problem in the code below is that is works perfectly if I compile with the -G options (for the generation of device code debug infos) but behave wrongly without.

```
double new_temp = d_computeNewTemperature(sommah,sommath);        
if(new_temp <= d_PTsol){
            printf("Solidified %.5f,%.5f\n",new_temp,d_PTsol);
            double newQuote = d_sbts_updated[d_getIdx(row,col,ALTITUDE)]+d_sbts_current[d_getIdx(row,col,THICKNESS)];
            //CODE FOR LAVA SOLIDIFICATION HERE
    }else{
           //there is lava and is not solidified -> activate this cell!
           adjustAdaptiveGrid(row,col);
 }
```

ouptutting something like this at a certain point of the simulation:

```
Solidified 1344.68654 1143.00000
Solidified 1343.99509 1143.00000
Solidified 1320.50061 1143.00000
Solidified 1325.53942 1143.00000
```

To make things more subtle the problem completly disappear if I change the the if condition to a strict inequality `if(new_temp < d_PTsol)`.

Compilation is carried out with the following options and in separate compilation mode

```
-O3 -Xcompiler -fPIC -std=c++11
```

and linking using

```
--cudart static --relocatable-device-code=true -gencode arch=compute_35,code=compute_35 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
```

Has someone faced a similar issue before? Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

The problem seem to be somehow related to the translation of the if else construct with the <=  as condition. Translating

```
if(new_temp <= d_PTsol) {
        //solidification
}else{
        //something else
}
```

to

```
if(new_temp <= d_PTsol) {
        //solidification
}
if(!(new_temp <= d_PTsol)){
        //something else
}
```

makes the code work perfectly.

Comment: This is often indicative of a race condition/unitialised memory/undefined behaviour. I suggest you run things through cuda-memcheck and it's subtools (racecheck, synccheck, initcheck).

Comment: @Jez I've already ran all the cudamemcheck suite: leak, race init and synch check. All passed cleanly. Then why should a race condition appear only when not compiling with device debug enabled? Moreover the new_temp variable is a register and is not obviously unitialised (it is printed out correctly!). Same holds for the variable `d_PTsol`.

Comment: I skimmed the question a bit too fast the first time around - sorry. This is indeed a strange problem. Have you been able to check whether the code after the print statement is executed? Maybe the print statement is being erroneously moved during optimization. A reproducing example would be useful.

Comment: I will try today to recompile everything different systems and  different  target devices and I'll tell update the question with further details. The print is not the only wrongly executed instruction (because this behavior cause numerical differences, that let me spot this "problem cadidate").

Comment: What CUDA version and platform are you running this on? It is possible this is a compiler or device runtime bug. It is also possible it has already been fixed in CUDA 7.

Comment: I'm running on Debian Jessie (kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64). CUDA platform 7.0 on a tesla k20c. gcc/g++ version 4.9.2.  Think is quite updated.

Comment: Well I could ask a lot of question here, like do you have any conditional thread behavior that either encompasses this statement or bisects it, are you using `__syncthreads()` in any of the code you haven't shown, etc. etc.  But SO actually expects an MCVE for questions like this, and you're likely to get a more satisfactory answer, quicker, that way.  (A link to a github repo with literally *no* instructions does not constitute an MCVE.)  It may well be a compiler bug, but without a short, simple reproducer, that avenue will get no traction.  I've voted to close for lack of an MCVE.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Added instructions on github readme and updated the question (thanks for pointing it out). I'm trying to construct a shorter and simpler example that exibith the same issue. Do you have any idea on how to investigate this kind of problem? (look at the assembly produced by the different version of the `if` maybe?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an similar issue. My code worked with -G option but not without. I just needed to add -fmad=false and -prec-div=false to the compiler options (for more information see: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation).

By default this values are true and optimise your single precision operations, but at the cost of your precision. If you enable debug mode this optimisation will be disabled. I needed exact values, therefore my code worked only with -G. Maybe you have a similar issue. (more information about CUDA floating point precision: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#mathematical-functions-appendix)